# simple nagios script failing

Tags: bash, scripting, nagios

What is wrong with the following if-then-else?  I never can hit the else.

```
if [ $result > $value ]; then
   echo HEALTH: OK.  Result is $result  Value is $value
   exit 0
 else
   echo HEALTH: CRITICAL.  Result is $result which is over $value
   exit 2
 fi


# ./check_cw_auto <AWS variables> 5.0
HEALTH: OK. Result is 275593.8 Value is 5.0

# ./check_cw_auto <AWS variables> 10000000.0
HEALTH: OK. Result is 275593.8 Value is 10000000.0
```

I'm trying to create a nagios bash script.  I did try -gt instead of >, but that give an error.  Example:

```
./check_cw_auto <AWS variables> 5.0 
./check_cw_auto: line 30: [: 256497.2: integer expression expected
HEALTH: CRITICAL. Result is 256497.2 which is over 5.0
```

Answer (score 4):

In `[]`, two strings are compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), not numerically.  You want to use `-gt` or `-lt`.

*Edit*: In response to your update, `bash` does not have floating point logic.  You need to use whole numbers.

Answer (score 4):

As you have a floating point number as part of the comparison you can use [bc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) to do the comparison, bc returns 1 if the comparison is true

```
if [ $(echo "$result > $value" | bc -q ) -eq 1 ]; then
   echo HEALTH: OK.  Result is $result  Value is $value
   exit 0
 else
   echo HEALTH: CRITICAL.  Result is $result which is over $value
   exit 2
 fi
```

Answer (score 0):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B.5B_.24foo_.3E_7_.5D.5D

It's being treated as a string comparison.

Use "-gt" instead:

```
if [ $result -gt $value ]; then
```